# How to verify the enabled Ciphers through OpenSSL in RHEL 8.5

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, java, openssl, ssl

Our Java Application is functioning on RHEL 8.5 OS platform with **TLSv1.2** protocol. Here, to improve the security, We want to enable only a few ciphers and need to block others.

***CIPHERS TO BE ENABLED:***
ChaCha20-Poly1305, AES-GCM, AES-CCM with the key exchange of ECDHE, DHE, RSA.

**NOTE:** All other ciphers need to be prohibited.

We have made the below changes in **"ssl.conf"** file.

```
   SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.2
   SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
```

But when we try to verify the ciphers from the server by using the
"openssl s_client -connect :443 -tls1_2" command, we are able to see only one cipher.

Please find the attachment    [image: SSL_Ciphers.png].

And If we add "!RC4:!aNULL" along with "SSLCipherSuite", we are ending with errors like "SSL handshake failure".

Please find the below Queries,

1. Whether the input on "SSLCipherSuite" is valid or not. If not, please let us know the corrections.
2. Please let us know the command to verify all the enabled ciphers.
3. How to block the ciphers other than those 3?

Thanks for the workaround solution.

Comment: Please try openssl ciphers -s -tls1_2 on the server.   This should list all the valid ciphers.

Comment: @user103944..Got many lists almost 25 ciphers for the above command. But In SSLCipherSuite, enabled only 4 ciphers. Please let us know how the others ciphers are enabled and how to block a few ciphers in that list.

Comment: Just want to be sure the ciphers you want are in the list.  The syntax looks ok,   As another check - if the site is open to internet, go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and put in the url to get an analysis of the configuration.

Comment: @user103944.. As we are using the intranet, we can't able to check the URL by using ssllabs.com/ssltest. Please let us know any other solutions.